# How to match opening and closing tags in Lark?

Tags: python, parsing, ebnf, lark-parser

I'm trying to create a parser using [Lark](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark) for [WordPress shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Formal_Syntax). The self-closing tags in the language have no differentiating features from standard opening tags, causing a fair bit of ambiguity even in perfectly valid syntax. I've got it mostly working, but am struggling matching the opening and closing tags with each other.

The following example contains a self-closing tag [a] and a tag [b][/b] with plaintext content:

```
[a][b] content [/b]
```

The relevant part of my language definition looks like this:

```
shortcode: shortcode_template{shortcode_name, attribute_list} | "[" shortcode_name attribute_list "]"
shortcode_template{name, attrs}: "[" name attrs "]" value "[/" name "]"
shortcode_name: /[^\[\]\<\>\&\/\s]+/
```

I expected that using a template for the opening/closing tag variant would do something akin to regex group logic, e.g. `"[" (name) attrs "]" value "[/" $1 "]"`, but this just seems te get unpacked into `"[" shortcode_name attribute_list "]" value "[/" shortcode_name "]"`, causing the above text to be parsed as:

```
value
  shortcode
    shortcode_template
      shortcode_name    a
      attribute_list
      value
        shortcode
          shortcode_name    b
          attribute_list
      shortcode_name    b
```

Is there an option to tell Lark that the name value in the opening tag should be the same as the name value in the closing tag?

Comment: No, this is not possible. What you have is not a CFG (context free grammar), and can not easily be parsed with Lark. You might be able to do some magic with a Postlexer/CustomLexer, but it is probably easier to just write your own parser/trying to reuse an existing parser (maybe a XML parser?)/using another parser library.

Comment: I see. Is there a term for grammar that is not context free? What feature would I need to search for in a parsing library to be able to parse something like this?

Comment: Context Sensitive Grammar (CSG). I do not know any good libraries, but a PEG library might be able to do this. (or something like pyparsing)