# How to create parametrized regex (by terms of C#) which matches strings delimited by custom multicharacter delimiter?

Tags: c#, regex, string, delimiter, multiline

So, I want to find strings in a text. The text can contain multiple lines. The strings can be delimited by custom delimiters - this should be parameterized. There can be multiple strings in the text, even in one line. For example: if the delimiter is (three double quatation marks): `"""` then in this text:

> lorem ipsum """findthis""" "but not this" 'nor this'
> """anotherstringtofind"""
>
> ""blabla"" """yet another""""""text to find"""

It should find: *findthis*, *anotherstringtofind*, *yet another*, *text to find*.
(Notice, that the delimiters are not present in the matched strings, although I can remove them using C#, if needed.)

I can do a similar thing, just for one character delimiters:
with regex: `"[{0}](([^{0}])*)[{0}]"`

Like this:

```
public static MatchCollection FindString(this string input, char delimeter, RegexOptions regexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline)
{
    var regexString = string.Format("[{0}](([^{0}])*)[{0}]", delimeter);
    var rx = new Regex(regexString, regexOptions);

    MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(input);

    return matches;
}
```

I guess, the solution would use look-ahead operators, but I could not figure out how to combine it with something, which has similar effect like `[^]` in case of single characters. Is it even possible to "negate" a whole sequence of characters (to not put them into the matches)?

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68813599/lark-matching-custom-delimiter-multiline-strings) is similar, but I'm not familiar with Python.

Some clarification:
My expectation is to use each and delimiter pair exactly once. So, e.g. this pass should pass:

```
            var inputText = "??abc?? ??def?? ??xyz??";

            var matches = inputText.FindString("??", RegexOptions.Singleline);

            Assert.Equal(3, matches.Count);
```

Is it possible to solve this in C# using regex?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with `string.Split`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lazy quantifier instead of negated character class. In you example with """ it should lead to regex like `"""(.*?)"""`

Also, notice that your current attempt incorrectly uses character classes for delimiters, as `["""]` is equivalent to `["]`, and in turn to simple `"`. Use your delimiter as is, without any additional wrappers.

But **don't forget to escape your delimiter** before use in regex. So, that if you have delimiter like `[]` in regex it should be `\[\]`.

Your method would look like this:

```cs
public static MatchCollection FindString(string input, string delimiter, RegexOptions regexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline)
{
    string pattern = string.Format("{0}(.*?){0}", Regex.Escape(delimiter));
    var rx = new Regex(pattern, regexOptions);
    return rx.Matches(input);
}
```

---

> Is it even possible to "negate" a whole sequence of characters

Yes, it is possible: [`(?:(?!foo).)+`](https://regex101.com/r/k2Z8Fy/1) can be used to match something like this. Or for your example `"""(?:(?!""").)*"""`. But it would be way worse performance-wise comparing to simple lazy quantifier.

Comment: Thanks, but {0}(.*?){0} only finds the first occurrence of the string. I would like to find all of them.

Comment: @Geff, what do you mean only first? Check out this [demo](https://ideone.com/II88dQ), if found both occurrences. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. First I tested this only with [regex101](https://regex101.com)  Seems like with wrong settings...
The provided code works.

Comment: @Geff, `.Matches` [Searches the specified input string for all occurrences of a specified regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=net-7.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-matches(system-string-system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-regexoptions-system-timespan)). To test the same behaviour on regex101 enable flag `g` - global.

Comment: """(?:(?!""").)*""" this one doesn't seem to work for me, though. It still finds the """ if I try it through regex101. In C# it throws an exception for the regex: System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' if I replace """ with {0}

Comment: @Geff, it should work. Consider this [demo](https://ideone.com/RBG1lc).

Comment: Well, if I change the input to:
" adas \"\"\"foo\"\"\" \"\"\"\"\"\"daf\"\"\"\"q\"\" a" then it will find foo and a space, but nothing else. For some reason it takes the second """ into account twice.

Comment: @Geff, it does exactly what is expected. There are 6 quotes there, it means three quotes,nothing,three quotes.